# How to load pdf worker javascript in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pdf.js

I have to display pdf thumb in wordpress and I'm using pdfjs. I want to load worker script in javascript but i don't understand how to load `pdf.workder.js` in javascript code. as i have only knowldge of `wp_enqueue_script` but dont know how to get script path.

`PDFJS.workerSrc ="path/pdf.worker.js";`

Now how to get path in javascript at runtime in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script inside your theme directory in the folder where also other js already should be (to keep cleaner the code in the theme) and to retrieve it just use:

`get_template_directory_uri()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

or:

`get_template_directory()`

if you want the absolute path to your theme

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

To get the folder of a plugin use:

`plugin_dir_path( string $file )`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/

or if you want the path just to the main plugin folder of WP and then manually add the path to your plugin use:

`plugins_url()`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url

Comment: i'm using plugin will use the same function ?

Comment: there is a function for retrieving directly the path to the given plugin, adding in the answer